# What is the difference between Docker Unix socket on ubuntu vs alpine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running through a problem where I can't mount **Unix docker socket** to an **alpine container** but works with **ubuntu container**.

**docker-compose using alpine image**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  cluster:
    image:  alpine  
    tty: true  
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"
```

running docker command in the alpine container:

```sh
/ # docker --version
sh: docker: not found
```

**docker-compose using ubuntu image**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  cluster:
    image:  ubuntu:20.04
    tty: true  
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"
```

running docker command in the ubuntu container:

```sh
root@5f30b4143c43:/# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

I don't get why I can access my host docker env using the ubuntu container but not with the alpine one? is there anything missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with the socket:

```
/ # docker --version
sh: docker: not found
```

You're seeing this because you're trying to run a binary compiled for `glibc` platform, while Alpine is built using [MUSL libc](https://musl.libc.org/).

You would need to install a version of the `docker` client built specifically for use under Alpine (or just pick almost any other image).

Comment: using docker:dind right? would that be the right choice?

Comment: I mean, I would just go for an official Fedora/Ubuntu/Debian/whatever base image, but you know your use case better than I do.

Comment: I'd use your image's distribution's package manager to install the `docker` binary, and not try to bind-mount it from the host.  Also remember that, if you can successfully run any `docker` command at all, you can root the entire host; think hard about whether you actually need to give the container this much power.